# How do I choose where a javascript code will generate a div at the press of a button?

Tags: javascript

So I have the following code for a button , it generates a div with text from a fieldd ( text that i type) and it generates it at the bottom of the page but I want it to generate it in a container above it.

```
function creatediv() {
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = document.getElementById('spatiu').value;

document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: So, append it to the container above instead of `body` ..? See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement

Comment: ```document.body.appendChild(div)``` should be ```myDiv.appendChild(div)``` where ```myDiv``` is a variable, selected with  ```document.getElementById('<my-div-id-here>')```

Comment: thanks! That was really helpful, its my second day of learning javascript so this may sound like childs work for u but its brand new for me :D I did it within seconds of reading this

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that the target container you want to be updated with the new child has the `id="container"` attribute. Then the code will be the following

```js
function creatediv() {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = document.getElementById('spatiu').value;
 
  const container = document.getElementById('container');

  container.appendChild(div);
}
```

The general idea is that you need to [find the container element](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp#:%7E:text=The%20easiest%20way%20to%20find,by%20using%20the%20element%20id.)
and [appendChild](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp) to it.

Comment: What about adding attributes to the div? What would that look like?  I mean generate the div with a specific border/width

Comment: If the target container is already in your HTML, you just need to add the attribute to this element (e.g `<div id="container"></div>` ). If you're creating the container dynamically using javascript, then you can use `div.setAttribute("id", "container");`